# String Format para XAML

Tags: c#, xamarin, xaml

Hola amigos necesito hacer un string format para tarjetas y quiero solo moestrar los ultimo 4 numeros de un binding, pero necesito hacer esto desde XAML . Yo se que puedo hacer esto desde la clase modelo y seria mucho mas sencillo, pero necesito hacer esto desde el XAML.

```
<Label Text="{Binding MaskedMopAccountNumber, StringFormat='???'}" />
```

Alguien sabe como puedo hacer esto?

Siguiendo el ejemplo sugerido tengo esta clase:

```
public class MopDTO : IFormattable
{
    public string MaskedMopAccountNumber { get; set; }

    public string ExpirationDate { get; set; }

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        switch (format)
        {
            case "Numeros":
                return MaskedMopAccountNumber.Substring(MaskedMopAccountNumber.Length - 4);

            case "ExpirationDate":
                 string exp = ExpirationDate;

                    if (ExpirationDate.Length == 3)
                    {
                        exp = ExpirationDate.Insert(1, " / ");
                    }
                    else if (ExpirationDate.Length == 4)
                    {
                        exp = ExpirationDate.Insert(2, " / ");
                    }
                return exp;
            default: return MaskedMopAccountNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Y mi Binding

```
<Label Padding="10" 
Text="{Binding MaskedMopAccountNumber, 
StringFormat='{0:Numeros}'}" />
 <Label
  Padding="10"
  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
  Text="{Binding ExpirationDate, StringFormat='{0:ExpirationDate}'}" />
```

Comment: La otra opción es utilizar un Converter, pues StringFormat no tiene esa funcionalidad a través de XAML. Posiblemente podrías hacerlo también a través de Patterns o Masks

Comment: si, hay forma de hacerlo desde xaml, pero debes preparar tu clase modelo.

Comment: podrias poner un ejemplo a ver si me es util, la cosa aqui es que no puedo mover el modelo, pero pues quiza pueda ajustar la solucion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para utilizar el stringFormat en tu clase Modelo, ejemplo `Cuenta` debes heredar de IFormattable

```
public class Cuenta: IFormattable
{
  public string MaskedMopAccountNumber {get;set;}

  public override Tostring(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
  {
      switch(format) 
      {
        case "Numeros": return MaskedMopAccountNumber.Split() //aca le das la conversion y tratamiento a tu valor como desees. 
        default: return MaskedMopAccountNumber;
      }
  }
}
```

En tu xaml:

tu Formato en este caso sera Numeros. Podes debugear y ver que valor entra en el switch, si es null ira directamente al default.
Por otro lado no lleva la propiedad que queres pasarle, porque ese valor te lo devuelve el StringFormat, y solo debes colocar un . `punto` en lugar de tu propiedad.

```
<Label Text="{Binding ., StringFormat='{0:Numeros}'}" />
```

Comment: Estoy tratando de hacer esto `case "Numeros": return MaskedMopAccountNumber.Substring(MaskedMopAccountNumber.Length - 4);` pero devuelve todo el string

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim, Perdón la demora, pero quitale el espacio, en el string.Format porque ahora entra null el format con ese espacio, te edito la respuesta. Podes debugear y fijarte que valor entra.

Comment: ya le puse unos break points al modelo pero no entra y tambien le quite el espacio. edite mi pregunta y no funciona ninguno de los case del switch, la vista se renderiza con los valores completos

Comment: cambia tu propiedad MaskedMopAccountNumber por un . para que quede asi:  `<Label Text="{Binding ., StringFormat='{0:Numeros}'}" />`

Comment: de la misma forma tu otra propiedad  <Label
  Padding="10"
  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
  Text="{Binding ., StringFormat='{0:ExpirationDate}'}" />

Comment: podrias explicarme que truco tan hacker es este o la referencia para leerla?

Comment: El truco es leer seguido los libros de C#, esto esta en el libro de Certificación de Microsoft 70-483, te lo aconsejo de leer hay cosas interesantes si queres aprender bastante a fondo c#. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformattable?view=net-5.0

Comment: Muchas gracias inge, prioridad numero uno a partir de hoy